# Keep some type of files when git merge

Tags: git, git-merge

I'm trying to merge 2 branches ( a and b ). I'm on the "a" branch and I want to merge it with the branch "b" but want to keep "pom.xml files" from a.
("b" have pom.xml files too but an old version of tag)
Do you know the best way to do this?

Thank you for your possible answer!

Comment: If that file has not been deleted from b nor was ever in b then there should be no issue. Why not merge and see?

Comment: "a" and "b" have pom.xml ( b have an old version tag) and they have lots of pom.xml files. Then i just want to keep "a" pom.xml files.

Comment: Have you tried merging? What was the result?

Comment: I got lots of conflict on the pom.xml file

Comment: Is there only one Pom file? Or many? If you have conflicts you can choose which branch you’d like to use.

Comment: Around 10 pom file. I know i can do it manually but i want to know if their is a command to do it automatically

Comment: https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/faq/solve-merge-conflicts

Comment: I know how to process to solve conflicts, but i want to see if it's possible to avoid upstream this conflicts.

Comment: Is someone else working on the code and pushing to the same remote?

Comment: Yes,we are around 8 to push regulary

Comment: Then there’s no way to completely avoid conflicts. If the files a generated, remove them from git, otherwise you should try and adopt a merging strategy, like git-flow, and use a pull-request style merge process.

Comment: Okey, Thanks for your help

Comment: Yeah. This is the result of a distributed version control.